# How to retrieve a URL string from a parameter value in PHP

Tags: php, url, get, url-parameters

I'm writing a "pipe" of sorts to rename and drop parts of an iCal feed. And I want the script to take different feed URL's as input.

It's source parameter value contains parameter separators and the parameters look like this:

```
?source=https://web.timeedit.se/hig_no/db1/timeedit/p/open/r.ics?sid=3&p=20130819.x%2C20131130.x&objects=160812.183&ox=0&types=0&fe=0&pp=f
```

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
<?php $params = $_GET;
$content = file_get_contents($params['source']);
// ...
```

But this will not work since the print_r of $_GET looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [source] => http://www.example.com/?source=https://web.timeedit.se/hig_no/db1/timeedit/p/open/r.ics?sid=3
    [p] => 20130819.x,20131130.x
    [objects] => 160812.183
    [ox] => 0
    [types] => 0
    [fe] => 0
    [pp] => f
)
```

How can I get the full URL and not just the [source] value? Alternatively, is there a better way to retrieve the URL? Preferrably one where I can just paste the URL into the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $_SERVER.

```
   function saveUrl() {

       $pageURL = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 

       $URL=urlencode($pageURL);

       return $URL;
   }
      $URL_ENC=saveUrl();
```

Comment: I added the use of substr to your answer. I hope you're fine with that. Will let you know if it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to edit it... this answer is meant as orientation in some direction not as a copy paste solution. Even though it is quite straight forward. Glad it was helpfull. Cheers.

Comment: Seems my edit was rejected. Here's what I added to get the URL string itself:
`substr($URL, strpos($line, 'https://'));`

Answer (score 0):

you must urlencode the source for example

```
source=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.timeedit.se%2Fhig_no%2Fdb1%2Ftimeedit%2Fp%2Fopen%2Fr.ics%3Fsid%3D3%26p%3D20130819.x%2C20131130.x%26objects%3D160812.183%26ox%3D0%26types%3D0%26fe%3D0%26pp%3Df%0A
```

now you will get full url in encoded format.

then use it like below.

```
$url = urldecode($_GET['source']);
```

this will have your full url